# IB Color Issues

Tags: ios, colors, xcode6, interface-builder

I noticed that when setting a UIView background in Xcode 6, the colors are different. I am setting the 1st view with a Hex of #414042 in interface builder. And the second view with `0x414042` in code with the following HEX TO RGB macro.

```
#define RGB(hexValue)                   [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

and as you can see there is a difference.

[image]

In IB there is a gear setting to change the RGB type, but after changing that and trying to set the RGB, it resets back to sRGB.

[image]

Anyone know a way around this so the hex colors in code will match the hex color in IB?

Comment: Please file a bug report: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: yep, just filed one.

Answer (score 0):

Is your iOS version 10+ ?
see this [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621930-colorwithred),
Apple changed default color space, so if you want to xib using the same color as code,on xib ,you need to choose `Device RGB`or `sRGB` , it is different with `Generic RGB`